# How to improve topology around an E-pole?

Tags: modeling, topology, geometry

I'm trying to find a way to make the area around the E-pole less stretched (marked in blue on the pics below) while keeping the mesh geometry as clean as possible. Is there any solution or method I could apply?

[image: Model Front View]

[image: Model Side View]

Just for info, the selected part in white will finally be separated from the rest.

As I'm quite new in 3D modelling, let me know any flaw you might notice on my model. Thanks in advance for your helpful feedback.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Blender stackexchange. It's hard to tell, since I don't know the purpose of your model. If it's for pure render purposes or game asset, you could always bake a normal map from a higpoly object to reduce the pinching effect. Other than that, the topology looks fine.

Comment: @metaphor_set Hi, it's going to be a low-poly but I also want it to be subdivision-ready if needed.

Comment: If you want to subdivide the mesh for sculpting purposes, I always suggest to start with a more or less evenly divided base mesh. In your case you should create some more loop cuts in the lower part, before you subdivide it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I finally got it right by simplifying the mesh a bit. First, I dissolved 3 edges-loops parts on the left side which were not contributing anything to the geometry. Then, I added 3 new vertical edges to the bottom face-loop with the knife tool. By doing so, the E-pole moved a bit higher on the left and is now no longer pinching (see pic below).

[image: Model Quad View]

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the subdivision in the mirrored area, it doesn't look bad. The only bit I'd be concerned about is that the bottom loop of faces are very long, and much larger than the others around the pole, which can sometimes cause problems.

Adding a cut/loop through these faces below the pole could fix that if it becomes a problem, see the red line for the approximate location:
[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. I tried it, it reduced the pinching slightly, but it was still noticeable despite this.